How to view a nilpotent cone as a scheme/variety?
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra over a field $k$. An element $x\in \mathfrak{g}$ is called nilpotent if $(\text{ad}_x)^r=0$ for some $r\in \mathbf{N}$. Define the nilpotent cone $\mathcal{N}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ to be the $k$-subspace consisting of all nilpotent elements.

How to realize $\mathcal{N}$ as a scheme over $k$?
I think question 1 is highly related to the following question. Let $G$ be a linear algebraic group over a field $k$, and let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra of $G$. By definition, $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra over $k$. However, some authors use the notation $\mathfrak{g}(k)$. I guess the reason why they use this notation is that they view $\mathfrak{g}$ as a $k$-scheme and $\mathfrak{g}(k)$ is the set of $k$-valued points. How do they view a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over $k$ as a scheme over $k$?


From MO: the nilcone is the scheme-theoretic fiber of the projection map $\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{g}// G$  where $\mathfrak{g}// G$ is the categorical quotient of the adjoint action.

@DietrichBurde Thank you for point out the post. To explain more about my question, I guess there is a general principle to view a $k$-vector space (perhaps with some additional structure) as a scheme over $k$. If one has such a principle, then Q1 and Q2 are solved at the same time.

To any vector space $V$ you can associate the affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(S(V^*))$ where $S(V)$ is the symmetric $K$-algebra of a $K$-vector space. Not sure it solves your question but there you go.

@CaptainLama So is this exactly the way how we view $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ as schemes?

It's possible that reading Section 2.1 in the following could give you a quick, bare-bones explanation of what you want: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.01768

@AlexYoucis Thanks a lot! This exactly answers my question.
